# How to implement Jcrop script in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jcrop

I'm looking for a way to allow users to crop images before uploading and I see jcrop script. Is it possible implement it wordpress?

Thank you
Best Regards

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: Please, could you explain me how to do it? Thank you

Comment: The stack community will gladly help if you add some effort yourself, first. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question accordingly :-)

Comment: Btw: your chances of getting an answer are higher here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/